# Unsupported or invalid query filter clause specified for property onPremisesSyncEnabled

Tags: microsoft-graph-api

I am trying to read the groups which are created in O365 using the below API
https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/groups

These group have few attributes which are not populated e.g. onPremisesSyncEnabled,onPremisesLastSyncDateTime and the value which is present in the system is **null**

But i am getting the below error when I execute the query when I use the null in the comparison
Please let me know how do we compare the variable to null.

Query for onPremisesLastSyncDateTime

```
https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/groups?$filter=onPremisesLastSyncDateTime ge null

{ error:
   { code: 'Request_BadRequest',
     message:
      'Unrecognized \'Edm.DateTime\' literal \'datetime\'null\'\' at \'30\' in \'onPremisesLastSyncDateTime ge datetime\'null\'\'.',
     innerError:
      { date: '2020-07-28T06:02:46',
        'request-id': '' } } }
```

Query for onPremisesSyncEnabled

```
https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/groups?$filter=onPremisesSyncEnabled eq null.
{ error:
   { code: 'Request_UnsupportedQuery',
     message:
      'Unsupported or invalid query filter clause specified for property \'onPremisesSyncEnabled\' of resource \'Group\'.',
     innerError:
      { date: '2020-07-28T06:09:56',
        'request-id': '' } } }
```

Example record of the DL which is created directly in O365. I have remove the displayName, name and the ID for security reasons.

```
{
id: 'id',
       deletedDateTime: null,
       classification: null,
       createdDateTime: '2018-11-04T02:17:10Z',
       creationOptions: [],
       description: null,
       displayName: 'DL ,
       expirationDateTime: null,
       groupTypes: [],
       isAssignableToRole: null,
       mail: '',
       mailEnabled: true,
       mailNickname: '',
       membershipRule: null,
       membershipRuleProcessingState: null,
       onPremisesDomainName: null,
       onPremisesLastSyncDateTime: null,
       onPremisesNetBiosName: null,
       onPremisesSamAccountName: null,
       onPremisesSecurityIdentifier: null,
       onPremisesSyncEnabled: null,
       preferredDataLocation: null,
       preferredLanguage: null,
       proxyAddresses: [Array],
       renewedDateTime: '2018-11-04T02:17:10Z',
       resourceBehaviorOptions: [],
       resourceProvisioningOptions: [],
       securityEnabled: false,
       securityIdentifier: '',
       theme: null,
       visibility: null,
       onPremisesProvisioningErrors: [] 
}
```

Thanks,
George.

Comment: Are you still looking for any help on this question

Answer (score 0):

After raising a request with Microsoft they had provided a solution.

The solution involves calling the beta endpoint as this functionality is not in GA.

1. Use Beta Endpoint (until we GA later in september)
   **https://graph.microsoft.com/beta/groups?$filter=onPremisesSyncEnabled ne true&$count=true**
2. ConsistencyLevel = eventual  **Request Header**
3. $count=true  **QueryString Parameter**

Thanks,
George.